# Multiple android apps

Tags: android

I need to make around 1000 android apps with same code base but different names, logos, splash screens,images . using android library will solve the issue? One google developer account is sufficient?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to do so.

If each app uses the same source code but different ressources, you should offer customization options within the main app.

You won't have good dev feedbacks by polluting the market this way.

With customizations, you can reach as much users as you would with a 1000 apps, because you could meet their needs properly.

Take a look at Inn-Apps billing in the official Android developer documentation...

Comment: I actually had such an offer. I am doing no wrong or crime. I have approximately 1000 clients who need a similar application but with their own names. And i am incorporating an android library module to show the genuinity behind all this.. Is there anything that can be done, say submitting to google beforehand regarding the purpose of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Google has [recently cracked down](https://techcrunch.com/2018/07/27/google-follows-in-apples-footsteps-by-cleaning-up-its-play-store/) on template apps, and you will likely have apps rejected and get your account banned if you attempt this under a single account:

> Apps that are created by an automated tool, wizard service, or based on templates and submitted to Google Play by the operator of that service on behalf of other persons are not allowed. Such apps are only permissible if they are published by an individually registered developer account belonging to the user of the automated tool, not the operator of the service.

You may be able to make this work for now if you create a new account for each app that you publish; however, there is no guarantee that Google won't change the Play Store terms of service to prohibit this as well.